# How to send Sonar Analysis report in email from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.5

I am using SonarQube Server 5.5 which doesn't suppport PDF report plugin

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to send a report at the moment.

Regarding the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Account#UserAccount-Notifications) you have following options to enable a notification:

- Changes in issues assigned to me or reported by me
- Issues resolved as false positive or won't fix
- My New Issues
- New issues
- New quality gate status

Perhaps you can define a [Quality Gate](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates) and if it fails or succeed you will receive a mail.